# Does the Spirit Guardians spell stack with multiple casters?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stacking

Recently played with a group, where 3 of their clerics would cast *spirit guardians*, claiming monsters in the area had to make 3 wisdom saves for 3d8 damage each, potentially adding up to 9d8 damage per round.

Is this any different then trying to have two casters cast *insect plague* or *cloudkill* on the same area, or *bless* on the same individual?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Multiple of the same spell never stack. *Player's Handbook*, “Combining Magical Effects”:

> The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. **The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however.** Instead, the most potent effect — such as the highest bonus — from those castings applies while their durations overlap.

With three casters of *spirit guardians* you can cover more ground, but you will never get more damage or saves out of them by overlapping them.

Comment: That's what I said.  Something about the spell description seems to have them saying this is a different case, then say, insect plague.  Probably that the AoE moves in this case.  Wow, did it plow through that room of yetis, though!

Comment: Well I need another angle.  Your argument did not convince that group.  Sorry don't want to turn this into a chat!

Comment: @Ἄρτεμις If you need another angle you might want to un-accept my answer, to make the question is more likely to attract new ones.

Comment: What about spells that have a duration of instantaneous like [Vitriolic Sphere](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93694/stacking-of-vitriolic-sphere), but have lasting effects?

Answer (score 19):

### Half speed does not stack, but damage should

> The **effects** of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the **most potent** effect — such as the highest bonus — from those castings applies while their durations overlap.

If *damage* is an *effect* of the spell, funny things can happen. Imagine two clerics (C1 radiant, and C2 necrotic) using this spell, in partially overlapping areas. Two enemies (E1 and E2) are running past them. E2 gets the damage twice, but E1 only once, as the radiant field "protects" him when he would enter the necrotic field.
**I really hope this is not intentional.**

[image: overlapping Spirit Guardians]

It seems [it is up to us](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/93123/9552) to decide what is an *effect* and what is not. I think if damage is not an effect, but a separate property of a spell, the game provides better simulation, while still keeping balance.

### Simulation

Two Dire Wolfs bite you, you get the damage twice (2x 2d6+3), but once you are prone, you won't get *proner*.

Analogously, you are in the area of two Spirit Guardians. You get the damage twice, but your speed is only halved once. Makes sense.

### Balance

Assume C1 has the Light domain, and he casts Wall of Fire in a 4th level slot, while C2 casts Spirit Guardians in a 3rd level slot. The enemy now takes 3d8+5d8 damage. Casting Spirit Guardians in this 4th level slot would decrease this damage to 3d8+4d8, so it is far from overpowered.

On the other hand, adding two (or more) Blesses together would be clearly overpowered, trivializing GWM for example. But Bless does not do damage, rather it is more like a condition.

### Conclusion

You might call it *interpretation*, you might call it *houserule*, the bottom line is the game makes more sense if *damage* is added together, but the *conditions (effects)* are not.

Comment: A curiosity to your example would be if C1 has 3d4 and C2 casts the spell with a higher slot and does 4d4, how would you reconcile the most 'potent' effect?  I have to agree that the damage would be rolled twice in that case. Though if an enemy would enter the center of the 2 then it would only take the most powerful.

Comment: You take damage when you enter the spell effect for the first time. Nothing in your example prohibits E1 from taking damage the moment he enters C2. No two of the same spell can effect him "at the same time." He is moving; it is a different time.  If this was a residual effect, he would only take damage from the highest source, as at that *time* he resolves the damage, he can only be effected once. Whether it is necrotic or radiant is irrelevant--the wording only talks about whether the *spell* is the same.

Comment: You may want to change the E1 arrow so it points up into the overlap.  But I agree with you completely.  There is no "duration" of the "effect" of taking damage (or healing).  They just happen.  Since the "duration" doesn't overlap, they add together just fine.

Comment: Doing a bit of necromancy here, but I think the way this resolves is that the area of the two Spirit Guardians can't overlap (whether they both do the same damage type or not). So the area in your image where C1 and C2 overlap would instead only be affected by whichever Spirit Guardians was cast at a higher level. If they are equally potent, then it would be up to the DM to decide how to resolve that. Then each Spiritual Guardians would be completely independent, so moving from one area into another would cause damage for E1 just as it does for E2.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is **No, game features do not stack.**

As pointed out in @SevenSidedDie's answer, in the Players Hand Book (PHB) the rules for spells are as such:

> The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine (PHB Chapter 9, "Combining Magical Effects")

However as some may point out, this seems fairly narrow of a description for what does not stack (e.g. spell effects cast, etc). There may be some room to argue things like two flaming spheres hitting a target at the same time should do double the damage (or in this case, two castings of Guardian Spirits). However, there was an update to the DMG. According to the official Errata:

> **Chapter 8**
>
> **Combining Game Effects (p. 252).** This is a new subsection
> at the end of the “Combat” section: “Different game features can
> affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features
> have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the
> most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap.
> For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form
> trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target
> is subjected to that trait again. Game features include spells,
> class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic
> items. See the related rule in the ‘Combining Magical Effects’
> section of chapter 10 in the Player’s Handbook.”

This seems fairly clear that the intended purpose is that no similar spell/ability/effect should occur on a target more than once.

Here is a link to the source material: http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf