# Do multiple instances of the Death Ward spell stack on the same target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stacking

In most situations, spell effects of the same name do not stack, per the rule on [combining game effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#CombiningGameEffects) added in the [errata for the DMG](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DMG-Errata.pdf) (p. 252):

> [...] when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. [...]

However, the *death ward* spell may be **an exception to the intent** of the rule. [*Death ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/death-ward) is unique compared to other durable buffs, because it both **replaces its trigger** and **ends when it triggers** (emphasis mine):

> The first time the target would drop to 0 hit points as a result of taking damage, the target **instead drops to 1 hit point**, and **the spell ends.**

I can see two possible interactions with multiple castings of *death ward*:

**Scenario A**

1. Carl has two instances of *death ward* active on him. Only the most recent one applies.
2. Carl takes a hit that would drop him to 0 hit points.
3. The active instance of *death ward* triggers, dropping Carl to 1 hit point instead and ending that instance of *death ward*.
4. Because Carl did not drop to 0 hit points, the inactive instance of *death ward* does not trigger.
5. Carl now has a single instance of *death ward* active.

In this scenario, Carl effectively has two stacks of *death ward*.

**Scenario B**

1. Carl has two instances of *death ward* active on him. Only the most recent one applies.
2. Carl takes a hit that would drop him to 0 hit points.
3. Both instances of *death ward* trigger. The activation of *death ward* causes Carl to drop to 1 hit point instead of 0 hit points.
4. Carl has no instances of *death ward* active anymore.

In this scenario, the instances of *death ward* do not stack. Note that this scenario is identical to the ones described in this Q&A: [What happens when identical overlapping effects have their end-condition met?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169347/what-happens-when-identical-overlapping-effects-have-their-end-condition-met)

Which of these scenarios is correct?

Comment: Related (and its various related links): [How do you determine the 'most potent effect' for overlapping spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93114/14878)

Comment: I understand that in the general case, multiple instances of the same spell do not overlap. However, death ward seems to be a special case, because it ends when it triggers.

Comment: At least related: "[What happens when identical overlapping effects have their end-condition met?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169347)" | "[Does the extra damage from Booming Blade stack if the spell is cast twice on the same target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103746)" | "[If two Ensnaring Strikes affect the same target, does it have to make two saves to be unrestrained?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136686)" | "[How do multiple castings of Hex affect a creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164223)"

Comment: I think it would be good to explain why the following question does not answer yours: "[What happens when identical overlapping effects have their end-condition met?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169347)". Your question, as far as I can tell, asks what happens when the overlapping, identical effects of *death ward* both have their end condition met

Comment: @Medix2 The crucial difference is that Death Ward replaces its trigger. Death Ward triggers when the creature drops to 0 hit points. After Death Ward resolves, the creature instead drops to 1 hit point. Other instances of Death Ward cannot trigger if checked after the first instance has resolved. The spells and effects mentioned in that question do not replace their trigger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when identical overlapping effects have their end-condition met?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169347/what-happens-when-identical-overlapping-effects-have-their-end-condition-met)

Answer (score 15):

It seems like this answer is still the same as given here: [What happens when identical overlapping effects have their end-condition met?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169347/what-happens-when-identical-overlapping-effects-have-their-end-condition-met)

Because as they say, it's an ambiguity in the rules. You'll have to make a ruling.

Is the Death Ward case special? That depends entirely on what your ruling is.

If your  ruling is "multiple triggered effects of the same type are resolved one by one, and only if their trigger is still valid after resolving the previous one", then yeah it's special and works differently.

If your ruling is "multiple triggered effects of the same type all trigger simultaneously", then it's not a special case and won't work differently.

Neither of these options seems more correct than the other, since the mechanics of the game are not this fine-grained. D&D is not a competitive game and there is no prize money on the line depending on how this interaction works out, so for the game it's fine to just "let the DM make a call" and either option will result in a working game, even if it's not a same at every table.

Comment: Do you know if apps like Roll20 account for this? Or in those apps, is it still the DMs job to figure that out?

Comment: @TKoL I don't know, I don't use any of these apps.

Comment: @TKoL Roll20 does not account of any rules. You simply have a D&D5e sheet with pre-programmed rolls and macros (like a Halfling rolling for Perception with Expertise and Advantage will, with a single button, roll 2 d20s, add Wisdom modifier, add Proficiency modifier twice, and if a 1 is rolled, it gets rerolled). But the players have to do things with the numerical values they get (subtract HP, for example). Roll20 has no concept of applied buffs, or matching attacks against ACs or anything else

Comment: @BlueMoon93 thank you. For some reason I was under the impression Roll20 did a huge portion of this type of work for you.

Answer (score 11):

### Both castings of *death ward* end at once

From the spell description for [*death ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/death-ward):

> The first time the target would drop to 0 hit points as a result of taking damage, the target instead drops to 1 hit point, and the spell ends.

The word "first" is the reason you can't have multiple *death ward*s trigger in sequence. As soon as you drop to 0 HP after they are cast, it will be the "first" time you do so, thus all of them trigger simultaneously. If only one triggered, then next would trigger on the "second" time you drop to 0 HP.

I suspect this is by design. Otherwise, you could go into a fate-of-the-world battle with hundreds of scrolls of *death ward* and be very hard to take down, because each time you were KO'd, a *death ward* would just get you back to 1 HP. (Unless they got dispelled, of course.)

To requote the original poster:

> [...] when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. [...]

It doesn't say that features with the same name won't trigger when their condition is met, it says that only one applies for the duration. When a character hits 0 HP, every single death ward cast on them triggers at once. Since they are all features with the same name, only one of them actually restores the character to 1 HP. Since all of the death wards have triggered, all of them immediately expire.

Comment: It contradicts the rule about "Combining Game Effects", since it is explicitly stated that only *one* effect takes place. Or do you think that this is a case of "specific beats general"?

Comment: @Eddymage See my updated answer, the combining game effects rule doesn't do anything to change things.

Comment: I see your argument now, it seems indeed a reasonable interpretation, given the ambiguity of the rules. I anyway read the quoted rule as "only one of the spell is active and takes place" as in Joe's answer, and I do not see the problem you report in your answer (i.e. going into a battle with a lot of Death Ward scrolls) given the spell level.

Comment: From the rules on Casting a Spell: "Each spell description begins with a block of information, including the spell's name, level, school of magic, casting time, range, components, and duration. The rest of a spell entry describes the spell's effect." So, if none of a spell's entry is part of its name, level, school, casting time, range, components, or duration, then it's part of its effect. Since the trigger of Death Ward is none of those, it's part of its effect. And since only the effects of the most potent casting applies, the trigger doesn't apply.

Answer (score 10):

It looks to me as if your quote gives you the answer.  (Short version: scenario 'A')

> when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap.

Death Ward 'A' is cast on target.
Death Ward 'B' is cast on target.

One of these is considered more potent (or at least has a longer duration).  Let's presume that 'A' is more potent (or considered so since it was cast first).

As a result - based on the quote above, only 'A' effects apply while the durations overlap.

Target is hit, and would drop to 0 hit points.  'A' effects still only apply at this point, so 'A' fires and the target is set to 1 hp.  'A' now ends.

Since the duration for 'A' has expired (the spell has ended), now 'B' is in effect.  The target is at 1 hit point, so 'B' does not fire, and is ready for the next blow.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] if you need any guidance in answering or posting questions! I completely agree with you, I just think that the *Death Ward* B applies  first, since it is the more recent.

Comment: To continue off what Eddymage said, the rules on [Combining Magical Effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects) state: "[...] The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, [...] the most recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent and their durations overlap. [...]" Though I do agree with your answer otherwise

Comment: I think it's important that the rule you're quoting applies on a _per-target_ basis. For example, an AoE spell can be suppressed for some targets (in an overlapping area) but active for others. In that context, we might need to ask whether the end condition of Death Ward is an "effect on a target" or whether it's...something else?