# Do 2 instances of the Booming Blade spell stack on the same creature, in terms of the damage it takes if it moves willingly?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, cantrips, stacking

I'm creating a NPC for a campaign that is a sorcerer using a longsword and the [*booming blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) spell (SCAG, p. 142). With the [Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option Quickened Spell, this NPC can cast *booming blade* twice per turn.

Do 2 instances of *booming blade* stack? I mean the part that reads:

> If the target willingly moves before then, it immediately takes 1d8 thunder
>   damage, and the spell ends.

If the NPC casts *booming blade* twice on the same target on their turn (once as a bonus action using Quickened Spell, and once normally as an action) and hits with both attacks, will the target take damage from both castings if it moves willingly?

Comment: Hi Rorp; I'm not sure the full description of the spell needs to be included in your question, especially since you highlight the part you're interested in at the end. I didn't remove it myself when I made some minor edits, but it might be worth removing it (not the bit at the end, though, keep that bit; just the full description about your actual question).

Comment: I think that it is usefull for the context, for peoples that read the question by curiosity and don't know the spell

Comment: I've closed your question as a duplicate because I feel [the marked one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103746) is asking the same thing. If you feel this is not the case, as always, feel free to [edit] the question and explain why

Comment: @Medix2 look like it was, but I couldn't find it, so I posted my question. Thanks

Comment: @rorp Yeah I'm debating whether to edit one of the tags to the "stacking" tag

Comment: @Rorp: As NathanS mentioned, we generally avoid unnecessary/excessive quotation of copyrighted material, especially non-SRD content. I've edited the corresponding quote out of your post, as the relevant portion is already quoted separately in the question. (Those unfamiliar with how the spell works probably shouldn't be answering questions about it anyway - and if they're interested, the source book and page number is now listed in the question.)

Comment: Relevant metas: [Is there any reason why quoting a D&D 5e spell in its entirety would not qualify as “fair use”?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8746/33569), [Does this answer to a question about a Vampire Discipline that lets them disbelieve in things have too much quoted text?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3084/33569), [Can non-open-license rules be discussed, or not?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6043/33569)