# Can I use the Illusionist's Bracers and the Twinned Spell metamagic to cast a twinned Booming Blade as both an action and a bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, actions, metamagic

The description of the [*illusionist's bracers*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/illusionists-bracers) (GGR, page 178) says:

> While wearing the bracers, whenever you cast a cantrip, you can use a bonus action on the same turn to cast that cantrip a second time.

The sorcerer's Twinned Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option (PHB, page 102) says:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and doesn’t have a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level to target a second creature in range with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).

Can I use Twinned Spell when I cast [*booming blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) (SCAG, page 142) as an action, **and** using the *illusionist's bracers*, twin-cast *booming blade* again as a bonus action (thus attacking 4 targets or the same 2 twice each)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: the [*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* errata from November 2020](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SCAG-Errata.pdf) changes *Booming Blade*'s range to self, making it uneligible for twinning specifically. The following applies to *Booming Blade* only if you don't use that errata.

---

The only general limitation on [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372), as stated in PHB, is:

> You can use only one Metamagic option on a spell when you cast it, unless otherwise noted.

But there is no limitation on how many times you can use metamagic per turn.  And the castings with these bracers are explicitly written to be two castings (first as an action, second as a bonus action), as quoted in your question.

So **yes**, you can twin the spellcastings as you describe, an action and a bonus action, in the same turn. You do have to spend sorcery points for both instances of Twinned Spell (2 sorcery points total, as both spells you're twinning are cantrips).

Comment: *Booming blade* now has a range of self and is not eligible for twinning.

Comment: It changes it to a range of "Self (5 feet)", which is different to a range of "Self".

Comment: @nick012000 given the stated intention of the Errata is to bring them in line with the Tasha's cauldron book release, I imagine we will get more detail on if there is a difference between "Self" and "Self (5 feet)" when that book is released in a week. As it currently stands, it still has a range of Self, regardless of any modifiers to the "Self" range

Comment: @illustro I'm just basing that off of some of Jeremy Crawford's Twitter conversations on the subject. Apparently a spell with a Range of "Self (XYZ)" means that you create a magical effect with an origin point of yourself, a shape/size of XYZ, and which targets other people within that area.

Comment: @nick012000 That's fair. I'm basing my comments off of this: "Some of the changes in these errata files bring elements of those two books in line with content in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything": https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice-compendium-nov2020

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, you can use two castings of twinned *booming blade*

*Booming blade* is a cantrip that targets only one creature, and as such it is eligible for the Twinned Spell [Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option. As long as there are two targets within the 5ft range of the spell you can twin the spell to attack both of them.  Illusionist Bracers allow you use a bonus action to cast the same cantrip a second time, so *booming blade* can be cast (and twinned) again as a bonus action.

Note that the *booming blade* effect will not stack on the same creature more than once, due to the rule on [combining magical effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects):

> The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect - such as the highest bonus - from those castings applies while their durations overlap, or the most recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent and their durations overlap.

If the second casting is on the same two creatures as the first, they will still only be affected by one instance of thunder damage should they choose to move.

Comment: Why will the secondary booming blade damage only trigger once?  If it's 2 separate attacks won't each attack trigger it once each?

Comment: @SamLacrumb: The answer should be edited to address this, but it's because of the [Combining Magical Effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects) rule: "The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect — such as the highest bonus — from those castings applies while their durations overlap, or the most recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent and their durations overlap."

Comment: @SamLacrumb V2Blast is correct, and I have added that to my answer. The _attack_ part of the spell can hit the same creature twice, but the _effect_ of the spell (surrounding them with booming energy) cannot combine, so only the most recent one applies.

Comment: @Sam FWIW, we *do* have [a question on simultaneous *booming blade* effects](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103746) where [my own answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/169344) states that it's complicated.